# jQuery UI Autocomplete Suggestions Not Closing on Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an odd problem with a jQuery UI autocomplete. I want it so that when the text field gets focus, a list of all options in the autocomplete comes up. This works, but when selecting an item by **clicking** on it, the suggestions stay open. I want the suggestions list to disappear like autocomplete normally works.

It works fine when you select the item with your keyboard, but when you **click** an item, the list just keeps reappearing again over and over again.

To make this problem weirder, the functionality works perfectly when just passing values manually. It only starts happening when I'm passing in a JSON source.

Any ideas!?

**Working Code** - http://jsbin.com/aFeceTe/1/edit?html,js,output

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var test = [ { value: "1",label: "Google" }, { value: "2", label:"StackOverflow" }, { value: "3", label:"Microsoft" }, { value: "4", label:"Yahoo" } ];

   $("input").autocomplete({
     source: test,
     delay: 0,
     minLength: 0,
     select: function(event, ui) {      
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(ui.item.label).attr('title', ui.item.label);
     }
  }).focus(function () {
      $(this).val('').autocomplete("search");
  });

});
```

---

**Broken Code** - http://jsbin.com/uyOGUVU/6/edit?html,js,output

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("input").autocomplete({
      source: 'http://jsbin.com/IdIXIRU/3/js',
      delay: 0,
      minLength: 0,
      select: function(event, ui) {      
         event.preventDefault();
         $(this).val(ui.item.label).attr('title', ui.item.label);   
      }
   }).focus(function () {
      $(this).val('').autocomplete("search");
   });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = true;
    $("input").autocomplete({
        source: 'http://jsbin.com/IdIXIRU/3/js',
        delay: 0,
    minLength: 0,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).val(ui.item.label).attr('title', ui.item.label);
            temp = true;
            return false;            
        }
  }).focus(function () {
       if(temp) {
         $(this).autocomplete("search");
         temp = false;
     }
   });
});
```

SEE [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uyOGUVU/15/edit)

Comment: Hmm, this is so close! The only problem is, if you double click on the text field, then click out of the box, then click in again, the autocomplete no longer works :(

Comment: Phew! Legend! I just added a close event to the autocomplete to reset the temp variable. I've added it to your code. Spent WAY too long getting this sorted. Thanks again